# (AS3) Error 1009 when trying to save data with SharedObject?

Tags: actionscript-3

No matter when I call my saveData function I just get error 1009. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong because I far as I can see nothing is null :/

All answers are appreciated in advance.

My Code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.SharedObject;

stop();

var Gold = 1;
var goldGain = 1;
var Diamond = 1;
var diamondGain =  1;
var saveDataObject:SharedObject;



function saveData(){
    saveDataObject.data.savedGold = Gold;
    saveDataObject.data.savedDiamonds = Diamond;
    saveDataObject.data.savedGoldGain = goldGain;
    saveDataObject.data.savedDiamondGain = diamondGain;
}
saveData();

function loadData(){
    Gold = saveDataObject.data.savedGold;
    Diamond = saveDataObject.data.savedDiamonds;
    goldGain = saveDataObject.data.savedGoldGain;
    diamondGain = saveDataObject.data.savedDiamondGain;
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventSaves)
function enterFrameEventSaves(event:Event){



}

playScreen_clickButtonMovieClipUp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playScreen_clickButton_stateChangeEventUp);                     
function playScreen_clickButton_stateChangeEventUp(event:MouseEvent){      
gotoAndStop(2);


Gold += goldGain;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`saveDataObject` is `null`; it isn't ever initialized.  It needs to be initialized before its members are, and the same goes for `saveDataObject.data`.  So:

```
saveDataObject = new Object(); // 1
saveDataObject.data = new Object(); // 2
saveDataObject.data.whatever = whatever; // 3
```

Of course, with that being a shared object (probably of type `SharedObject`, instead of just `Object`), initialization in your case would be a bit more complicated and would depend on your requirements.  You would have to keep up with which client initialized which `SharedObject` in which app instance, and you would need a system to pass the same reference around without it getting confused.

Also as a side note, it's usually better to type your variables and functions.  Even if you occasionally need to leave them untyped, it's better to do so explicitly by saying `var someVariable:*`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Panzercrisis said in his answer, `saveDataObject` [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) object is null that's why you got that error. You have to initialized it like this :

```
var saveDataObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal('put_your_object_name_here');
```

Then, you can save or load your `SharedObject` data :

```
// verify if we have already saved some data in our SharedObject
if(saveDataObject.data.savedGold){
    // then we load it
    loadData();
} else {
    // else we save default values 
    saveData();
}
```

For more details, you can take a look on this [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#includeExamplesSummary) from help.adobe.com.

Hope that can help.